# Something like the weak Whitney embedding theorem for continuous maps and homotopy.

Tags: geometric-topology

This is sort of a reference request. Consider a continuous map of orientable topological manifolds $f:N\longrightarrow M$ of dimension $n$ and $m$ respectively.

I have been told that there is a theorem something like "if $m>2n$ then $f$ is homotopic to an embedding" however I am having trouble finding such a result. We have this in the form of Whitney's embedding theorem if the manifolds are smooth but I am wondering about the more general case of a topological manifold (most importantly I want to relax the conditions to just a continuous map, not a smooth one).

Maybe there are some further hypotheses needed like $M$ being closed or compact, or simply connected. Can anyone point me to a reference for such a theorem?

Comment: Maybe this is contained in the weak embedding theorem. I don't have a good reference for any of this stuff beyond wiki.

Comment: I believe this answers my question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34658/is-there-a-whitney-embedding-theorem-for-non-smooth-manifolds/34698#34698